# Как можно реализовать прыжок к точке?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нашёл пример с помощью которого CharacterController может прыгать, но не получается его переделать так чтобы он прыгал в определённую точку/дистанцию, а jumpHeight при этом сам калькулировался основываясь на скорости и гравитации, я нашёл эту статью в [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Conditions_at_an_arbitrary_distance_x), но я даже не знаю с чего начать.

```
    public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 6f;
        public float jumpHeight = 8f;
        public float gravity = 20f;
    
        private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    
        CharacterController controller;
    
        void Start()
        {
            controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }
    
        void Update() {
        

    if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Я не могу найти примеры для CharacterController, хотя для Rigidbody нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

- Ты знаешь стартовый **X, Z** (координата прыгуна) `pA`
- Знаешь **X, Z** пункта назначения `pB`
- Приблизительно знаешь время прыжка `t`.  Можно просто засечь опытным путем время прыжка на месте.

А вот ни дано тупо вектор движения `pB-pA` поделить на время `t` и задать получены вектор **X, Z** при прыжке?

Comment: ответ хороший, но лучше бы написать в более мягкой форме

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылочка на доки [ссылочка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html)

```
void Update()
{
    if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
     }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

Comment: Да, но там обычный прыжок, а нужен в точку или на определённую дистанцию.